# Zero-truncated Poisson model

Tags: variance, mean, poisson-distribution, glmm, exponential-family

In the theory of generalised linear models, you may use the exponential family to find the mean and variance of certain distributions. How would the mean and expectation of the zero-truncated Poisson model be calculated from the exponential family?

f(y; θ, φ) = exp 
{[yθ − b(θ)]/φ
+ c(y, φ)}

f(y; λ) = (e^−λ*λ^y)/
y!(1 − e
−λ)

Comment: First note that it's a one-parameter exponential family, so no $\phi$ to worry about. (You're thinking of the exponential dispersion model.)

Answer (score 1):

For the Poisson model we have $f(y;\lambda)=e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}$ for $y=0,1,2,\dots $. The probability that $y=0$ is $e^{-\lambda} $, so for the zero-truncated Poisson model we get the model function (after some algebra)
$$
   f(y;\lambda)= \frac{1}{e^\lambda -1} \cdot \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}, y=1,2,3,\dots
$$
Taking the logarithm (natural) we get
$$
 \log f(y; \lambda) = -\log(e^\lambda -1) + y \log \lambda -\log y!
$$
so the density in exponential family form becomes (with $\theta = \log \lambda)$
$$
f(y; \theta) = \exp\left( y \theta - \log(e^{e^\theta} -1) -\log y!\right)
$$
so with your notation (leaving apart $\phi$ as suggested in comments) we have
$b(\theta) = \log(e^{e^\theta} -1), c(y) = -\log y!$.